# Error while running unit tests for CRIU 1.8

Tags: linux, unit-testing, flock, aio

I am trying to run the unit tests on CRIU 1.8. To prep the box, I installed:

libprotobuf-lite8
libprotobuf8
zlib1g-dev
libprotobuf-dev
libprotobuf-c0
libprotobuf-c0-dev
libprotoc8
protobuf-c-compiler
protobuf-compiler
libaio-dev
libcap-dev

After that, as root, I ran, `make test` and got the following output:

```
...
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/criu-1.8/test/zdtm/live/static'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/criu-1.8/test/zdtm/live'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/criu-1.8/test/zdtm'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/criu-1.8/test'
make zdtm
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/criu-1.8/test'
./zdtm.sh -l > zdtm-tst-list
================================= CRIU CHECK =================================
prctl: PR_SET_MM_MAP is not supported, which is required for restoring user namespaces
Error (cr-check.c:634): Kernel doesn't support PTRACE_O_SUSPEND_SECCOMP
Error (cr-check.c:683): Dumping seccomp filters not supported: Input/output error
Error (timerfd.c:55): timerfd: No timerfd support for c/r: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Error (cr-check.c:780): AIO remap doesn't work properly
Error (cr-check.c:796): fdinfo doesn't contain the lock field
============================= WARNING =============================
Not all features needed for CRIU are merged to upstream kernel yet,
so for now we maintain our own branch which can be cloned from:
git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/gorcunov/linux-cr.git
===================================================================

make -f Makefile.zdtm zdtm_nons
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/criu-1.8/test'
gcc  -O2 -Wall -Werror -DCONFIG_X86_64 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE    zdtm_ct.c   -o zdtm_ct
flock zdtm_mount_cgroups ./zdtm_mount_cgroups
flock: ./zdtm_mount_cgroups: Text file busy
make[3]: *** [mount_cgroups] Error 69
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/criu-1.8/test'
make[2]: *** [zdtm] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/criu-1.8/test'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/criu-1.8/test'
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

I assume my issues are the ones inside the CRIU CHECK block there, but I'm just not sure what I am seeing here. Can anyone point me in the right direction. If Google was helpful, then I was just too ignorant to recognize it. Thanks!

Also, I don't have the reputation on SO to tag this as CRIU (apparently that's a new tag), but it is clearly related to CRIU. If you agree and have the power, please throw a tag on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a new Linux kernel.

The stuff in that CRIU CHECK box is all about things that it requires, but are not supported by either the libraries on your system (e.g. libc), or by the kernel.  In the box below, they describe where you'll have to get the kernel that has the necessary patches:

```
============================= WARNING =============================
Not all features needed for CRIU are merged to upstream kernel yet,
so for now we maintain our own branch which can be cloned from:
git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/gorcunov/linux-cr.git
===================================================================
```

Follow the instructions on the CRIU installation page on how to configure the kernel: https://criu.org/Installation.  And, use a page like the one at "kernel newbies" for general advice on building the kernel yourself: http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelBuild.

Building a kernel is fairly straightforward, but it can sometimes be tricky to get it working correctly.  Make sure to leave a fallback kernel in GRUB, and consider having some sort of "live" bootable Linux ISO accessible to get back into your system in case it totally goes south.

Comment: I had a feeling. We had a guy on the team that built a custom kernel for our project, so I will shuttle this over to him. After I posted, I tested this out on stock Ubuntu 14.04 and got the same result. So I was less convinced it was something we did and more that there was something just missing in general. Luckily I am doing this in VMs, so if I destroy something it is of little consequence...

Comment: Great!  If you found my answer useful, please accept it.

Comment: So... it turns out for our specific situation, the installation page did not help. Apparently we had done all of those things. We see what needs to be done and are considering between doing it (contractually, I cannot be more specific) and upgrading to the latest version of CRIU. Regardless, the info you gave was very helpful, so I am marking it as answered.